# Function call not working in a function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>


void clearKeyboard(void){
    while(getchar()!='\n');
}


void pause(void){
    printf("Press <ENTER> to continue...");
    clearKeyboard();
}


void printWelcome(void){
    printf ("---=== Grocery Inventory System ===---\n\n");
}



int getInt(void){
    int iVal;
    char charCheck='x';
    while (charCheck != '\n'){
            scanf ("%d%c",&iVal,&charCheck);
            if ( charCheck != '\n'){
                    clearKeyboard();
                    printf ("Invalid integer, please try again: ");
            }
    }
    return iVal;
}


int getYesOrNo(void){

    //list of variables declared and initialized
    char ch;
    int ret;
    ch = 0;
    ret = 0;

    //it will keep asking the user as long as they don't reply with y or n
    while(ch != 'Y' || ch != 'y' || ch != 'N' || ch != 'n')
    {
            scanf(" %c", &ch);
            clearKeyboard();

            if (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y'){

                    ret = 1;
                    return ret;

            }
            else if (ch == 'N' || ch == 'n'){
                    ret = 0;
                    return ret;
            }
            //if they type other than y or n, it will print out this message
            else{
                    printf("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable: ");
            }
    }
    return ret;


}




int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit){
    int iVal;
    do{
            iVal = getInt();
            if (!(iVal >= lowerLimit && iVal <= upperLimit))
                    printf ("Invalid value, 0 <= value <= 7: ");
            }while (!(iVal >= lowerLimit && iVal <=upperLimit));
    return iVal;
}




int getMenuChoice(void){

    int SEL;
    int temp;
    printf("1- List all items\n");
    printf("2- Search by SKU\n");
    printf("3- Checkout an item\n");
    printf("4- Stock an item\n");
    printf("5- Add new item or update item\n");
    printf("6- delete item\n");
    printf("7- Search by name\n");
    printf("0- Exit program\n> ");
    scanf("%d", &SEL);
    if (SEL > 7){
            temp = getIntLimited(0,7);
    }
    return SEL;
}


void GrocInvSys(void){
    int SEL;
    int DONE = 0;
    SEL = 0;
    printWelcome();

    while (DONE == 0){
            SEL = getMenuChoice();
            clearKeyboard();
            if (SEL == 1){
                    printf("List Items!\n");
                    pause();
            }
            if (SEL == 2){
                    printf("Search Items!\n");
                    pause();
            }
            if (SEL == 3){
                    printf("Checkout Item!\n");
                    pause();
            }
            if (SEL == 4){
                    printf("Stock Item!\n");
                    pause();
            }
            if (SEL == 5){
                    printf("Add/Update Item!\n");
                    pause();
            }
            if (SEL == 6){
                    printf("Delete Item!\n");
                    pause();
            }
            if (SEL == 7){
                    printf("Search by name!\n");
                    pause();
            }
            if(SEL == 0){
                    printf("Exit the program? (Y)es/(N)o): ");
                    DONE = getYesOrNo();
            }
    }

}

int main(void){
    GrocInvSys();
    return 0;
}
```

For this code, it would display all the items in the getMenuChoice and whenever use types the number for each item, it would print a special message.

Everything is working fine, however it should say "Invalid value, 0 < value < 7: " whenever I type something other than 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7.

So I am guessing my getIntlimited function is not working in the getMenuChoice function. Any guesses to why?

p.s. I have typed pause(); for every if SEL == statement,is there any way I can make it better?

Comment: That entire `while` condition should be chained by `&&`, not `||`. As is, it is pretty much useless. A character cannot be two values simultaneously, so one of those not-equal conditions will always be true. It may as well be `while (1)` and if that is the intent, then just do that.

Comment: Your `getInt` function looks fishy.

Comment: Note that `clearKeyboard()` needs to account for EOF too: `int ch; while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') ;`.  Also, you should check the return value from `scanf()`; if it isn't 2, you've got problems.  Only when you know you have both a number and another character should you check that the extra is a newline.

Comment: As a general rule, try to avoid inverted logic.  You have `if (!(iVal >= lowerLimit && iVal <= upperLimit))` where the `!` is not really necessary.  De Morgan's theorems allow you to write: `if (iVal < lowerLimit || iVal > upperLimit)` which is easier to read — you don't have to push down a context after the `!` operator, evaluate the expression, and invert it.  Also, it is generally better to prefer `while` loops over `do … while` loops.

Comment: The fault is in `getMenuChoice()`. It looks like you have some leftover code in there.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is some excess code in `getMenuChoice()`. It just needs to print the menu and return the value of `getIntLimited(0,7)`:

```
int getMenuChoice(void){
    printf("1- List all items\n");
    printf("2- Search by SKU\n");
    printf("3- Checkout an item\n");
    printf("4- Stock an item\n");
    printf("5- Add new item or update item\n");
    printf("6- delete item\n");
    printf("7- Search by name\n");
    printf("0- Exit program\n> ");
    return getIntLimited(0,7);
}
```

Another problem is the call to `clearkeyboard()` after the call to `getMenuChoice()` in `GrocInvSys()`. This reads more input up to the next newline, but `getInt()` has already read the newline that terminated the integer. There is no need to read another line, since its contents are just ignored. Remove that call to `clearkeyboard()` to fix that problem.